# Why my route's page is blank ？

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My route:

```php
Route::get('admin/config/putfile', 'Admin\ConfigController@putFile');
```

My method:

```php
public function putFile()
{
    $config = Config::all();
    dd($config);
}
```

[image: blank route]

---

if I use 'admin/config-putfile'  or 'admin/configputfile', both is OK

just can't use  '/' !

why?

[image]

Comment: in dd(); write something else to check that, is your request reaching in this method first.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your Laravel log file?

Comment: no error, just blank page

Comment: Is your storage folder writeable by the web server?

Comment: use Config::getItems(); instead of Config::all(); and try

Comment: @无名小路 My answer is help for you then i wlil add to in answer

Comment: still blank
even I wirte  dd(111);    still  blank

Comment: @无名小路 Use Route::get('admin/configPutfile', 'Admin\ConfigController@putFile'); route instead of Route::get('admin/config/putfile', 'Admin\ConfigController@putFile'); and check

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd  Yes, Route::get('admin/configPutfile', 'Admin\ConfigController@putFile');  is OK.  But why I can't ues '/'?  In my other controller I can use '/'!

Comment: @无名小路 Are you use any middleware or route::group on this route ?

Comment: @无名小路 Please provide your .htaccess

Comment: Do you have another route with a `admin/config/{param}` url? Or a resource route with `admin/config`?

Comment: @无名小路 And for testing purpose please change route as Route::get('test/config/putfile', 'Admin\ConfigController@putFile'); and check its work or not

Comment: @iArcadia  Yes I have resource route with admin/config

Comment: Mmh, maybe that your `putfile` route is defined before your `resource` one?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd  I find the reason!  I have a resource route with `admin/config`,   and when I put the `admin/config/putfile` behind the resoure route, then the problem is solved.

Comment: @无名小路 ohh ok good

Comment: @iArcadia  Yes! you got it!  Thanks! I don't know I have to put it before Resource route!

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd sorry, it is 'before', not 'behind'. Put the `admin/config/putfile` before the `resoure route`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @iArcadia

I have a resource route with `admin/config`, and when I put the `admin/config/putfile` before the `resoure route`, then the problem is solved.